# UML: Modelling association between class and interface

Tags: java, uml

I have the following classes and interfaces:

```
public interface IPersistentObject { }

public class PersistentObject implements IPersistentObject { }


public interface IPersistentObjectDAO { }

public class PersistentDAO implements IPersistentObjectDAO { }


public interface IService1 { }

public class Service1 implements IService1{ 

   @Autowired
   private IPersistentObjectDAO persistentDAO;
}


public interface IService2 { }

public class Service2 implements IService2 {

   @Autowired
   private Iservice1 service1;
}


public class Bean {

   private IService2 service2 = JSFUtil.resolveBean("service2");
}

<bean name="service1" class="Service1"/>
<bean name="service2" class="Service2"/>
```

My question is: How should i modelling these associations?

If it can help I'm using JSF, Spring and Hibernate

Comment: with a class diagram? i don't get what JSF, Spring and hibernate would change in your UML model.

Answer (score 0):

If you use interface, it means what your model should be

JSF bean/ inject - interface->implemented class(DAO)->DB entity

So your JSF beans should find and inject Spring interfaces.

Spring service can be separated jar, which you can inject to JSF front end .

in jsf

```
   @ManagedProperty("#{handlerService}")
    private HandlerService handlerService = null;
```

Spring

```
@Service("handlerService")
@Component
public class HandlerService {

    @Autowired
    private DomainService domainService;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just modeling, just look here: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html You will have to point FROM the class that implement TO the interface. Like: "Service2" ---l> "IService2"

If it's something else, please clarify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Interfaces, the relation to its implementors is called "realization" not "generalization".

And it goes from the Interface to the Class that realize it, see below.

Class ----> Interface